# Using jquery to populate UL list but is not calling a seperate JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Summary: I have developed a map with leaflet. I have an UL li with bays. Once an UL Li item is clicked it will zoom to that bay using a JavaScript function. The UL is populated, by hard coding the bays in and now i have changed to a json file with the bays being called by a jquery function to populated the Ul li with bays.

The problem is, when the Ul li is populated with the bays,  it doesn't call the JavaScript function anymore and will not zoom to a specific bay once a specific bay is clicked.

Below i have explained my code.

I have a standard html un-ordered list  like the following

```
<li id="Irish Continental Shelf"><a>Irish Continental Shelf</a></li>
```

when an item is selected the following JavaScript function is called:

```
document.getElementById('Irish Continental Shelf').addEventListener('click', function () {
IrishContShelf();
var text = document.getElementById("mytext");
text.value = "Irish Continental Shelf";
});
```

This function zooms to a specific area on a leaflet map depending on the Id that is chosen.

But now I want to add in a more dynamic list from a json file such as:

```
var data = {
"users": [
{ "Id": "Irish Continental Shelf" },
{ "Id": "Irish Exclusive Economic Zone" }]}
```

Then a jquery function populates the un-ordered list like:

```
function list(){
$(data.users).each(function () {

  // add in id of data variable

    var output = "<li id= " + this.Id + "><a>" + this.Id + "</a></li>";
    $('#placeholder').append(output);
});}
```

The ul that will be populated:

```
 <ul id="placeholder" style=" height:400px;
  overflow:scroll;" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"   >
```

What i do not understand, even though when i create the li and give the 'id' attribute for the dynamic UL li the same id as the static UL li, it will not call the JavaScript function, and zoom to a specific area.

Any idea on where i am going wrong?

Comment: Adding an event handler for each separate entry is pointless. Use a single handler and add `data-` attributes to the items to find the target bay.

Comment: Can you show the code where you attach the event listener to your dynamically generated content?

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler on `#placeholder`. e.g. `$('#placeholder').on('click', 'li', function(){ var $li = $(this); DO STUFF HERE });`

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough HTML to show a full example, but as per my comment:

You need to use a delegated event handler on `#placeholder`. e.g.

```
$('#placeholder').on('click', 'li', function(){ 
    var $li = $(this); 
    // DO STUFF HERE (Like extract data attributes from the LI to determine where to go next)
});
```

This listens for click events bubbling up from elements inside the 'UL' element with `id="placeholder"`, *then* applies the `li` selector, *then* calls the function for any matching elements that caused the event.

This will work with dynamically added content as it listens at the UL instead of on each LI.